# $Ext_F$ vanishes if $F$ is a field?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the universial coefficient theorem for cohomology, we have split exact sequence $0 \to Ext(H_{n-1}(C),G)\to H^n(C;G)\to Hom(H_n(C),G)\to 0$, where $H_n(C)$ are homology groups for a chain complex $C$ and $G$ is a chosen group.

It is said that if $G=F$ is a field, then we have isomophism $H^n(C;F)=Hom(H_n(C),F)$ because $Ext_F$ vanishes since $F$ is a field. I don't know why $Ext_F$ vanishes under this circumstance? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: While $\operatorname{Ext}_F$ surely vanishes if $F$ is a field, the claims that $H^n(X,F)=\operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C),F)$ and that $\operatorname{Ext}(H_{n-1}(C),F)=0$ are false, or at least require more precision. What is $H_n(C)$ ? an abelian group or a vector space over some other field $k$ ? What about the $\operatorname{Hom}$ set ? Is it the set of additive morphisms or the set of $k$-linear ones ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For $Ext(A,G)$ we have to consider short exact sequences of $\mathbb Z$-modules $0 \to A \to B \to G \to 0$. If $G$ is a field, we do not automatically get $G$-vector space structures on $A, B$.

Comment: @Paul: sorry, there's more to say here; I had in mind the variant of the universal coefficient theorem where you take everything with coefficients in a PID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay, we can take a PID $R$ and consider short exact sequences of $R$-modules $0 \to A  \to B \to G \to 0$ to define $Ext_R(A,G)$. If $R$ is a field, then these sequences split. But we can't say much if $R$ is not a field even if $G$ has the additional structure of some field.